# How can I embed a file (pdf, excel, word etc.) into a lyx pdf document like it happens in word document?

Tags: lyx, embedding

I am creating a document in LyX for processes in which I want to include reference excel file, images etc. Is it possible for me to embed them in the output pdf like it happens in word instead of the embedded file being opened up and shown as pages in the output document.

Sorry if this has been answered before but I'm unable to find anything that can help solve this in LyX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you don't get answers, consider making your question more precise. I don't really understand what you've got and what you actually want to achieve; maybe the same holds true for others. Maybe an example as concrete as possible helps to clarify your intentions.

Comment: see the `attachfile2` package

Comment: The question is clear enough. Some PDF formats allow you to "attach" or "embed" a file, which does not need to be PDF. It is a method for delivering content that is not printed like the PDF text. With appropriate software, the reader can detach the file, and save it. Then the saved file can be opened by appropriate software (such as MS Word or Excel). As noted above, there is a package for that. However, it may or may not interact well with Lyx.

Comment: Lyx will no interact in any way with this package because have not any type of dialog to attach files, but nothing prevent you to add  raw TeX code in the body of the document (Ctrl-L) and the package in the LaTeX preamble. If it can work in LatEX, it can also work in LyX.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle for the solution. It solved the challenge I was facing. Thanks everyone else as well :). Have a nice day!